# Is Von Neumann entropy in QFT related to the two-point function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, entropy, quantum-entanglement, greens-functions, correlation-functions

Suppose I have a scalar QFT. Is the Von Neumann entropy related to the two point function? More generally, given the two point function and an entangling surface, can we calculate the Von Neumann entropy? If not, say we know all possible $n$-point functions, then can we calculate the Von Neumann entropy?

Comment: Obviously you can do this for a Gaussian state, see [here](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/cond-mat/0212631/). More generally I would be surprised if the two point functions alone were enough to calculate the von Neumann entropy. My intuition is the higher order correlator carry information and that should be reflected in the entropy. Conversely I would expect the logarithm in the von Neumann formula to depend on the reduced density matrix to all orders